# Java does not run with error "No such file or directory", despite it exists and is x86_64

Tags: java, executable

The file exists but bash complains it doesn't when asked to execute it.

```
$ ./Libs/openjdk-1.8.0_60-eap/bin/java
bash: ./Libs/openjdk-1.8.0_60-eap/bin/java: No such file or directory

$ ls -l ./Libs/openjdk-1.8.0_60-eap/bin/java
-rwxr-xr-x 1 spacecamel spacecamel 7734 Mar  4 03:27 ./Libs/openjdk-1.8.0_60-eap/bin/java
```

I've read this problem happened when a 32bit version was executed on a 64bit system. Unfortunately it does not seem to be my case

```
$ file ./Libs/openjdk-1.8.0_60-eap/bin/java
./Libs/openjdk-1.8.0_60-eap/bin/java: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.9, not stripped

$ uname -a
Linux <hostname> 3.14.34 #1-NixOS SMP Thu Jan 1 00:00:01 UTC 1970 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

```

Comment: Related:  http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/91577/cannot-execute-binary-no-such-file-or-directory/91578#91578

Answer (score 1):

This is indeed a typical error relating to the wrong architecture. However, it's also indicative that the necessary libraries required to run the executable are not found.

You need to add your x86-64 libraries for the Java run-time to the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, or add the directory containing them to the directory `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/`. To do this, first convert your `./Libs/openjdk-1.8.0_60-eap` into an absolute path. In my suggestions below I've assumed `/opt/java/Libs/openjdk-1.8.0_60-eap`.

**Without root access (or for testing)**

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/java/Libs/openjdk-1.8.0_60-eap
./Libs/openjdk-1.8.0_60-eap/bin/java
```

**With root access**

```
sudo -s
    echo /opt/java/Libs/openjdk-1.8.0_60-eap >>/etc/ld.so.conf.d/java
    ldconfig
./Libs/openjdk-1.8.0_60-eap/bin/java
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ldd` on java to see if there are libraries missing.

You can use strace to see if a file is missing or if it is `dlopen()`'ing some file.