# How to use libraries installed by nix at run-time?

Tags: path, non-root-user, dynamic-linking, nix, altlinux

I'm using `nix` in "single-user mode" in a system where I'm not the root (see below for a description of my nix setup).

I wanted to quickly run one of my binaries which is dynamically linked with a library which is absent in the system.

So, I've installed the library with `nix`:

```
$ nix-env -qa 'gmp'
gmp-4.3.2
gmp-5.1.3
$ nix-env -i gmp-5.1.3
```

But the library is still not found by the linker:

```
$ ldd -r ../valencies 
../valencies: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.15' not found (required by ../valencies)
../valencies: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by ../valencies)
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffbbf28000)
    /usr/local/lib/libsnoopy.so (0x00007f4dcfbdc000)
    libgmp.so.10 => not found
    libffi.so.5 => /usr/lib64/libffi.so.5 (0x00007f4dcf9cc000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007f4dcf748000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib64/librt.so.1 (0x00007f4dcf540000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f4dcf33c000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f4dcf11f000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f4dced8b000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f4dcfde7000)
undefined symbol: __gmpz_gcd    (../valencies)
undefined symbol: __gmpn_cmp    (../valencies)
undefined symbol: __gmpz_mul    (../valencies)
undefined symbol: __gmpz_fdiv_r (../valencies)
undefined symbol: __gmpz_fdiv_q_2exp    (../valencies)
undefined symbol: __gmpz_com    (../valencies)
undefined symbol: __gmpn_gcd_1  (../valencies)
undefined symbol: __gmpz_sub    (../valencies)
symbol memcpy, version GLIBC_2.14 not defined in file libc.so.6 with link time reference    (../valencies)
undefined symbol: __gmpz_fdiv_q (../valencies)
undefined symbol: __gmpz_fdiv_qr    (../valencies)
undefined symbol: __gmpz_add    (../valencies)
undefined symbol: __gmpz_init   (../valencies)
undefined symbol: __gmpz_ior    (../valencies)
undefined symbol: __gmpz_mul_2exp   (../valencies)
undefined symbol: __gmpz_xor    (../valencies)
undefined symbol: __gmpz_and    (../valencies)
symbol __fdelt_chk, version GLIBC_2.15 not defined in file libc.so.6 with link time reference   (../valencies)
undefined symbol: __gmpz_tdiv_qr    (../valencies)
undefined symbol: __gmp_set_memory_functions    (../valencies)
undefined symbol: __gmpz_tdiv_q (../valencies)
undefined symbol: __gmpz_divexact   (../valencies)
undefined symbol: __gmpz_tdiv_r (../valencies)
$
```

Look, it is present in the filesystem:

```
$ find / -name 'libgmp.so.10' 2>/dev/null 
/nix/store/mnmzq0qbrvw6dv1k2vj3cwz9ffdh05zr-user-environment/lib/libgmp.so.10
/nix/store/fnww2w81hv5v3dl9gsb7p4llb7z7krzd-gmp-5.1.3/lib/libgmp.so.10
$
```

What do I do so that libraries installed by `nix` are "visible"?

Probably, the standard user-installation script of `nix` modifies `.bash_profile` to add its `bin/` into `PATH`, but does not do something analogous for libraries.

#### My nix setup:

The only thing I have asked the root to do for me was: `mkdir -m 0755 /nix && chown ivan /nix`, otherwise I've followed the standard simple nix installation procedure. So now I can use custom programs from nix packages. I couldn't do this nicely without any help from the root at all, i.e., without `/nix/`, because `/nix/` was not available for me; I could of course use another directory, but then the pre-built binary packages wouldn't be valid and all packages would have to be rebuilt, according to the nix documentation. In my case, it was simpler to ask for `/nix/` for me.

Another thing I've done is adding to `~/.bash_profile`:

```
export NIX_CONF_DIR=/nix/etc/nix
```

so that I can edit `nix.conf`. (It was supposed to be in the root-controlled `/etc/` otherwise. I did it because I wanted to `build-max-jobs` and `build-cores` settings in it.)

Comment: I've never heard of `nix-env`, not to mention `nix.conf`. What OS is this? Also, what do you repeated references to `nix` mean? I've only ever heard it used as an abbreviation to `Unix`, but it seems you are using it in a more specific context.

Comment: @FaheemMitha I thought the tag had some description so I don't need to explain this in the post. But apparently the tag has no description. Oh, well, so I have to put in some links. `nix` is [a modern package manager](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/8665/4319), and nixOS is a distro, and Hydra is a system for constantly rebuilding nix packages, and nixOps is a tool to manage an infrastructure (a network of several hosts) declaratively, and disNix to manage a set of services declaratively (on top of an infrastructure). `guix` is a GNU offspring of `nix`, with a distro (promoted as 100%libre IIC

Comment: I see. Thanks for the information. I have heard of none of those except `guix`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### TL;DR

The working solution is using `patchelf` (if you have to deal with non-matching glibc versions: in the host system and the one nix libs have been linked with), see the second half of my story.

## Trying the usual approach

#### Trying to use LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Well, I have set up an environment variable for this in `~/.bash_profile`:

```
NIX_LINK=/home/ivan/.nix-profile
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$NIX_LINK"/lib
```

but that's not all!

Now there are problems with linking with different versions of `libc`:

```
$ ldd -r ../valencies 
../valencies: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.15' not found (required by ../valencies)
../valencies: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by ../valencies)
../valencies: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /home/ivan/.nix-profile/lib/libgmp.so.10)
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff365ff000)
    /usr/local/lib/libsnoopy.so (0x00007f56c72e6000)
    libgmp.so.10 => /home/ivan/.nix-profile/lib/libgmp.so.10 (0x00007f56c7063000)
    libffi.so.5 => /usr/lib64/libffi.so.5 (0x00007f56c6e54000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007f56c6bd0000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib64/librt.so.1 (0x00007f56c69c7000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f56c67c3000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f56c65a6000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f56c6211000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f56c74f1000)
symbol memcpy, version GLIBC_2.14 not defined in file libc.so.6 with link time reference    (/home/ivan/.nix-profile/lib/libgmp.so.10)
symbol memcpy, version GLIBC_2.14 not defined in file libc.so.6 with link time reference    (../valencies)
symbol __fdelt_chk, version GLIBC_2.15 not defined in file libc.so.6 with link time reference   (../valencies)
$
```

#### Sorting out 2 versions of glibc

The most surprizing error here is:

```
symbol memcpy, version GLIBC_2.14 not defined in file libc.so.6 with link time reference    (/home/ivan/.nix-profile/lib/libgmp.so.10)
```

because `nix` must have installed the version of `glibc` which is used by its `libgmp`!

And indeed, the `glibc` from `nix` is there:

```
$ ldd -r /home/ivan/.nix-profile/lib/libgmp.so.10
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff0f1ff000)
    /usr/local/lib/libsnoopy.so (0x00007f06e9919000)
    libc.so.6 => /nix/store/93zfs0zzndi7pkjkjxawlafdj8m90kg5-glibc-2.20/lib/libc.so.6 (0x00007f06e957c000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f06e9371000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f06e9da7000)
symbol _dl_find_dso_for_object, version GLIBC_PRIVATE not defined in file ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 with link time reference (/nix/store/93zfs0zzndi7pkjkjxawlafdj8m90kg5-glibc-2.20/lib/libc.so.6)
/home/ivan/.nix-profile/lib/libgmp.so.10: error while loading shared libraries: __vdso_time: invalid mode for dlopen(): Invalid argument
$
```

Probably, `glibc` was not available to the user, so when I ran my binary, the system's `glibc` was loaded first. Proof:

```
$ ls ~/.nix-profile/lib/*libc*
ls: cannot access /home/ivan/.nix-profile/lib/*libc*: No such file or directory
$
```

Ok, we can try to make `glibc` visible to the user, too:

```
$ nix-env -i glibc
```

Then everything is bad:

```
$ ldd -r ../valencies 
/bin/bash: error while loading shared libraries: __vdso_time: invalid mode for dlopen(): Invalid argument
$ /bin/echo ok
/bin/echo: error while loading shared libraries: __vdso_time: invalid mode for dlopen(): Invalid argument
$
```

So, it seems to be not an easy job if you want to load libraries from `nix` when running your own binaries...

For now, I'm commenting out

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$NIX_LINK"/lib
```

and doing in the shell session:

```
$ unset LD_LIBRARY_PATH
$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Need to think more. (Read about [__vdso_time: invalid mode for dlopen()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13668457/94687): having another `glibc` in `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is expected to crash, because your `ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` will not match your `libc.so.6`. Having multiple versions of glibc on a single system is possible, but slightly tricky, as explained in this answer.)

## The needed solution: patchelf

So, the path to the dynamic linker is hard-coded in the binary. And the dynamic linker being used is from the system (from the host glibc), not from nix. And because the dynamic linker doesn't match the glibc which we want and need to use, it doesn't work.

A simple and working solution is [patchelf](http://nixos.org/patchelf.html).

```
patchelf --set-interpreter /home/ivan/.nix-profile/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 ../valencies
```

After that, it works. You still need to fiddle with `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` though.

```
$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/ivan/.nix-profile/lib:/lib64/:/usr/lib64/ ../valencies
```

If--like in my imperfect case--some of the libraries are taken from nix, but some are taken from the host system (because I haven't installed them with `nix-env -i`), you **have to** specify both the path to the nix libs, and to your host system libs in `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` (it completely overrides the default search path).

#### additional step: patchelf for the library search path

(from the `patchelf` page)

Likewise, you can change the `RPATH`, the linker search path embedded into executables and dynamic libraries:

```
patchelf --set-rpath /opt/my-libs/lib:/foo/lib program
```

This causes the dynamic linker to search in `/opt/my-libs/lib` and `/foo/lib` for the shared libraries needed by program. Of course, you could also set the environment variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, but that’s often inconvenient as it requires a wrapper script to set up the environment.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the Nix's “single-user mode”, I provide an answer for [NixOS](https://nixos.org/) users. You usually [can't run binary files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/91578/11397) on NixOS.

If you install packages locally using `nix-env -i`, all your `.so` files are stored in `~/.nix-profile/lib/`.

If you install packages [globally](http://nixos.org/nixos/manual/index.html#sec-declarative-package-mgmt) by specifying them in `/etc/nixos/configuration.nix`, your corresponding `.so` files can be found in `/nix/var/nix/profiles/system/sw/lib/`. More correctly, only symlinks to corresponding files somewhere in `/nix/store/` are in that directory.

So if you install packages globally, [Ivan Zakharyaschev's solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/190736/11397) becomes:

```
$ patchelf --set-interpreter /nix/var/nix/profiles/system/sw/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 ./YOUREXECUTABLE
$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/nix/var/nix/profiles/system/sw/lib ./YOUREXECUTABLE
```

For the first command to work you'll have to install `glibc` globally. You can also modify the second command if you have packages installed both globally and per-user:

```
$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/YOURUSERNAME/.nix-profile/lib:/nix/var/nix/profiles/system/sw/lib ./YOUREXECUTABLE
```

It might be that the needed `.so` file simply isn't installed in the system, so you'll have an error like:

```
./YOUREXECUTABLE: error while loading shared libraries: libX11.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I'm not sure how to find a corresponding package for a missing file in general, but you can google the name of the `.so` file and install the corresponding package and try to run your executable with a custom `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` again.